My new deadbolt locks with key from outside but lock knob on inside will not turn unless key is in outside lock
I installed a new Atlas deadbolt and thought I followed the directions carefully.  The store keyed it to my original Kwikset key and the key turns the deadbolt with the key in the outside lock, the inside knob also locks and engages the deadbolt whether the door is shut or open.  When I remove the key, leave the door open or shut the door, and try to turn the inside knob to engage the deadbolt the knob will not turn.

This is probably a "timing problem". Remove from door, recenter things, and reinstall. More details would require getting my paws on the hardware.

Also look for a connecting shaft that's 180 degrees out of phase.
